# How to call a Javascript function when clicking on a pdf document loaded in a webpage?

Tags: php, javascript, pdf

I need to invoke a javascript function when I click on a pdf document loaded in a webpage. The code which I have written as follows. But it is not working.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function buttonEvent(msg){
    alert(msg);
}

</script>
<embed src="sample.pdf" id="buttonEmbed" width="500" height="600" type="application/pdf"
 onClick="buttonEvent('buttonClicked')"/>
```

Comment: Not likely. Perhaps a plugin can help

Comment: As far as I know, you can't use event listeners on embedded content like that. The embedded application will catch the mouse clicks.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Maybe there is another way to approach this.

Comment: My requirement is almost like this. The pdf document which is loaded might be different for different users and when they click on the pdf, I just want to display a popup and its content is some thing related with the pdf id.

Comment: Can you do it on load or does it need to be on click?

Comment: Yes I need to be call the js function on click, Otherwise it will be awkward each time user come to the page.

Comment: You could put a `div` over the `embed` element (different layer) and assign the `onclick` event to the `div`, then be sure to remove the `div` after the click as well.

Answer (score 0):

The PDF is loaded with a plugin and is not part of your DOM model. That's why listening event handlers other than onload for the embed node is not possible.

**Alternative solution**

You could add a button <kbd>display more</kbd> at the top or bottom of the PDF outside the embed container. Add your click event to this button.

Comment: Thanks Michel Feldheim. I've found another solution instead onclik popup with a flash screen like div at the top of the pdf viewer on document ready.  Thanks Nicarus for your time..